# How can I show folder size and number of items in folder detail in Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco-share

I want to show folder size and number of all the subordinate files(not sub-folders) for each folder in Alfresco Share.

How can I show this information on Folder Details as the following?

Name: Alfresco

Title: Alfresco Share

Description: Alfresco Discussion

Creator: admin

**Size: 128,08 MB**

**Files: 12**

**Sub-Folders: 2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\");
    int NumerSubDirs = info.GetDirectories().Length;
    int NumFiles = info.GetFiles().Length;
    FileInfo[] fileinfos = info.GetFiles();
    float totalSize =0;

    foreach (FileInfo infof in fileinfos)
    {
      totalSize += (infof.Length / 1024 / 1024);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Number of subdirs -> " + NumerSubDirs.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Numer of files -> " + NumFiles.ToString());
     Console.Write("Size of files -> " + totalSize.ToString());
```